Tried to install new theme
so i tried to switch the theme out and now i see this (IMG 1) then i try to go to the appearance section (just thinking its a theme error) then i see pic 2, and 3
image 1
image 2
image 3
When I tried to install another theme I get image 3

How did you install the theme? From the WP repo, uploading a zip in the Dashboard or via FTP/SCP?

Yes, I went to appearance and installed from there, but as you see in pic 3when I try installing another one now I get the error shown

This is looking like a permissions issue. Check to see if the user PHP runs as has write permission to the themes directory.
